# Как на discord.py написать команду по которой бот будет кикать определённого человека?

Tags: discord, discord.py

Нужно что бы при вводе команды kickm бот кикал человека с сервера, но ничего не происходит. В чем ошибка?

```
mistik = [294519237072912386] #ID пользователя которого должно кикать

@bot.command
async def on_message(message):
  if message.author.id not in whiteList:
    async def kickm(ctx,member:discord.mistik):
      await member.kick(mistik)
```

Comment: Да научитесь же вы читать [документацию!](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=kick#discord.Guild.kick)

Comment: Но самое главное, научитесь, пожалуйста, читать собственный код. Вы не делаете в коде никаких действий вообще. Абсолютно никаких. Сделали проверку айдишника и объявили корутину... Что дальше? То, что под `async def` не выполнится само собой. Учите, пожалуйста, синтаксис.

Answer (score 0):

Во-первых, **on_message** - это ивент, который выполняется при отправке сообщений, его декоратор должен выглядеть так:

```
@bot.event или @bot.Cog.listener()
```

Во-вторых, как уже сказали в комментариях, в вашем коде функция "**kickm**" не выполнится, т.к вы её не вызвали. Также, вместо "**discord.mistik**", нужно было написать "**discord.Member**".

И вот как должно примерно быть:

```
from discord import Member

@bot.command()
async def kickm(ctx):
    # ID пользователя
    member_id = 255236215612236
    member: Member = ctx.guild.get_member(member_id)

    await member.kick(reason=f'{ctx.author} Выгнал {member}')
```

Comment: Большое спасибо за ваш ответ, но остался один вопрос: как сделать, что бы по команде кикало только пользователя айди которого я выберу, а не того кого при вводе команде выберет пользователь?

Comment: @StrangeDylan, изменил.

Comment: @StrangeDylan, если вам нужно, вы можете дать возможность использовать команду пользователям с определёнными правами.